# How to choose appropriate epsilon value while approximating gradients to check training?

Tags: gradient

While approximating gradients, using actual epsilon to shift the weights results in wildly big gradient approximations, as the "width" of the used approximation triangle is disporportionately small. In [Andrew NG-s course](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/deep-neural-network/numerical-approximation-of-gradients-XzSSa), he is using 0.01, but I suppose it's for example purposes only.

This makes me wonder, is there a method to chose the appropriate epsilon value for gradient approximation based on e.g. the current error value of the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the epsilon value is a hyperparameter and the error value is an evaluation metric. Given that, cross-validation can be used to find the epsilon value than minimizes the error value.